# Jenkins reinstallation from Repository

Tags: jenkins, installation, repository, debian

I got a normal Jenkins installation on a Debian 7 host and I now want to transition to a Jenkins installation out of the repositories. Is there anywhere a Howto to be found which explains what is to be done in this case.

I searched everywhere for it, but didn't find anything. I'd like to keep all build jobs of the old installation and get that off the host and install the repository version.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add install Jenkins from a Debian repo? http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/. You should back up your jobs before hand to make sure